# Sequelize Mysql - Unable to Insert model with one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**`Design Overview:`** I've an application with Invoice creation and Inventory management features in it. Let's first understand the database design with 2 entities that we have as below:

1. Invoices
2. Items

Now, here I've a M:N relationship between these 2 entities because one invoice can contain multiple items and one item can be included in many such invoices.

So, I've created a 3rd table which we call joining table to associate these entities as shown in the image below,

[image: database-design-img]

**`Problem Statemet:`** I'm unable to insert model in the **child table(invoice_items)** using include attribute. Look at the code below to understand what's wrong happening here?

**3 Model Classes as below:**

**1. Invoice:**

**`Note:`** Providing with fewer attributes to keep it short.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Invoice = sequelize.define('Invoice', {
        invoiceId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        invoiceNumber: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(6).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }, 

        invoiceTotal: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        },

        paymentTotal: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        },

        invoiceDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, 
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
            allowNull: false
        }

    }, {
        underscored: true
    });

    Invoice.associate = function (model) {
        Invoice.belongsTo(model.Customer, {
            as: 'customer', 
            foreignKey: {
                name: "cust_id",
                allowNull: false
            } 
        });

        // association with 3rd table 
        Invoice.hasMany(model.InvoiceItem, {
            as: 'invoice_item', 
            constraints: true,
            onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
            foreignKey: {
                name: "invoice_id",
                allowNull: false
            }
        });

    };

    return Invoice;
}
```

**2. Item:**

**`Note:`** Providing with fewer attributes to keep it short.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
        itemId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        itemName: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: ''
        },

        // this is a opening stock
        quantityInStock: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },

        unitPrice: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        }

    }, {
        underscored: true 
    });

    Item.associate = function (model) {
        // association with 3rd table 
        Item.hasMany(model.InvoiceItem, {
            as: 'invoice_item', // alias name of a model
            constraints: true,
            onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
            foreignKey: {
                name: "item_id", 
                allowNull: false
            }
        });

    };

    return Item;
}
```

**3. Invoice_Item:**

**`Note:`** Providing with fewer attributes to keep it short.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const InvoiceItem = sequelize.define('InvoiceItem', {
        invoiceItemId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        quantity: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },

        rate: {
            type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(9,2),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0.00
        }
    }, {
        underscored: true 
    });


    InvoiceItem.associate = function(model) {
        InvoiceItem.belongsTo(model.Invoice,          {
            as: 'invoice', 
            foreignKey: {
                name: "invoice_id",
                allowNull: false
            } 
        });

        InvoiceItem.belongsTo(model.Item, {
             as: 'item',
             foreignKey: {
                name: "item_id",
                allowNull: false
            } 
        });
    }

    return InvoiceItem;
}
```

**Now, I'm using below code to create an invoice with the list of items in it. But, this is not inserting the child records in the joining table(`invoice_items`). What's wrong here in the code  below?**

```js
invoice = await Invoice.create({
                "invoiceNumber": req.body.invoiceNumber,
                "invoiceDate": req.body.invoiceDate,
                "invoiceTotal": req.body.invoiceTotal,
                "paymentTotal": req.body.paymentTotal,
                "cust_id": req.body.customer.custId,
                invoice_items: [{
                    item_id: 1,
                    quantity: 2,
                    rate: 300
                }]
            }, {
                include: [{
                    association: InvoiceItem,
                    as: 'invoice_item'
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Did you try to indicate `invoice_item` instead of `invoice_items` as an array of invoice items?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well but I'm getting an error saying, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Function._conformInclude(project_path\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js)`

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many variations, I understand that there was a problem in the association of my model classes. And, below is the way of associating both `Invoice` and `Item` model classes for M:N(Many to Many) relationships. I can now update the join table(invoice_items) by inserting the record in it for each invoice we create in the system with the items in it.

```js
Invoice.associate = function (model) {
  // association in Invoice model class
  Invoice.belongsToMany(model.Item, {
    through: 'InvoiceItem',
    constraints: true,
    onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
    foreignKey: {
        name: "invoice_id", // foreign key column name in a table invoice_items table
        allowNull: false
    } 
  });
};
```

```js
Item.associate = function (model) {
  // association in Item model class
  Item.belongsToMany(model.Invoice, {
    through: 'InvoiceItem',
    constraints: true,
    onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
    foreignKey: {
        name: "item_id", // foreign key column name in a table invoice_items
        allowNull: false
    } 
  });
};
```

**Create Invoice with Items in it:**

**`Note:`** Passing itemId (1) as a parameter in the addItems() method. If you have multiple items in an invoice then you can add `forEach` loop here to iterate over each item and individually pass the `itemId`, `quantity` and `rate` for an item sold to the customer.

```js
// first create the invoice
invoice = await Invoice.create(invoice);

// Next, add record in the join table
await invoice.addItems([1], {
  through: {
      quantity: item.quantity,
      rate: item.rate
  }
});
```

**Database Tables with one Test Result:**

**1. Invoice Table:**

[image: invoice-table]

**2. Invoice_items Table(Join Table):**

[image: invoice_items_table]